# BBOX in GLIGEN inference

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, generative-art

I need to ask in what format is the locations in gligen_inference.py? https://github.com/gligen/GLIGEN The images are generating completely out of order so I'm wondering what it could be? Here is the code snippet:

```py
def gen_location():
    min_size = 0.075

    x1 = round(random.uniform(0, 1 - min_size), 8)
    x2 = round(random.uniform(x1 + min_size, 1), 8)

    y1 = round(random.uniform(0, 1 - min_size), 8)
    y2 = round(random.uniform(y1 + min_size, 1), 8)

    return [x1, y1, x2, y2]



if __name__ == "__main__":


    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--folder", type=str,  default="generation_samples_2", help="root folder for >


    parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=1, help="")
    parser.add_argument("--no_plms", action='store_true', help="use DDIM instead. WARNING: I did not >    parser.add_argument("--guidance_scale", type=float,  default=7.5, help="")
    parser.add_argument("--negative_prompt", type=str,  default='longbody, lowres, bad anatomy, bad h>    #parser.add_argument("--negative_prompt", type=str,  default=None, help="")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    phrases = load_phrases('DATA/phrases.txt')
    dict_list = []

    dict_list = []

    for phrase in phrases:
        random_locations = gen_location()  # Generate random locations
        x = dict(
            ckpt="/home/paperspace/GLIGEN/gligen_checkpoints/diffusion_pytorch_model.bin",
            prompt=phrase,
            locations= random_locations,
            phrases = ["strawberry"],
            alpha_type=[0.3, 0.0, 0.7],
            save_folder_name="generation_box_text_v3"
        )
        dict_list.append(x)

    sample_meta = dict_list[0]
```

Xyxy cxcyhw hwcxcy etc

Comment: Typo error if name == "main": should be if __name__ == "__main__":

Answer (score 0):

Ok error is in list i need to do [random_locations] Thx.